# Solving $r^2 u_{rr} + 2ru_{r} + r^{2}u = 0$ directly

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The problem I am working on boils to solve the differential equation $$r^{2}u_{rr} + 2ru_{r} + r^{2}u = 0.$$ The solution to this equation is the spherical Bessel function $u(r) = \sin(r)/r$. However, let's suppose I didn't recognize the solution was a spherical Bessel function, is there a way to solve this ODE directly?

Comment: Bessel functions are just shorthand for a specific series. You could try a series solution to the ODE.

Comment: try a change of variable $y = ru$

Comment: Have you studied any techniques for solving ordinary differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the equation rewrite it as

$$r^2(u_{rr} + \frac{2}{r}u_r + u) = r\left[\frac{d^2}{dr^2}\left(ru\right) + (ru)\right] = 0$$

leaving us to solve $y_{rr} + y = 0$ where $y = ur$. This equation has the general solution $y = A\sin(r) + B\cos(r)$. Regularity at $r=0$ (this condition is usually imposed) implies $B=0$ and we are left with

$$u(r) = \frac{y}{r} = A \frac{\sin(r)}{r}$$

But in general, without imposing this condition, the full solution reads $u(r) = A \frac{\sin(r)}{r} + B\frac{\cos(r)}{r}$.